# Excel - Set cell background color if invalid character entered

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following code to detect a change in a specific column, if the user enters an invalid character I want to change the cells background color.

I thought `ActiveCell` was what I should use, but that returns a runtime error.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
activeRow = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveColumn = ActiveCell.Column

If ActiveColumn = 9 Then

Other code here...

Else

    If ActiveColumn = 7 Then
        If Target Like "*[!%^:~#|@.;`\/""*$,]*" Then
            ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    End If
   
End If
End Sub
```

Could someone advise how to set the background of the cell that has just been edited.

Thanks

UPDATE.
I've stripped this back to the basics and I can get it to work using:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'If Target Like "*[\!%^:~#|@.;`\/""*$,]*" Then
         Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    'End If

End Sub
```

Any cell I change gets a red background, But as soon as I uncomment the `IF/End If` it stops working. I don't understand why.

Comment: `Target` is the cell(s) in question.

Comment: The cell is referenced by the `Target` range supplied to the function, so test the `Target.Column` property. If you want the data in the cell use `Target.Value`. Use `Target.Interior.ColorIndex` to change the colour etc.

Comment: Using `Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3` I still get the run time error.

Comment: Also, if you type in say cell A1 and hit enter, when the function runs, Target points to A1 but Application.ActiveCell now points to A2, so it isn't really what you want anyway.

Comment: What is the specific error message and what line throws it? Note that you'll have a Type Mismatch error on `If Target Like "*[!%^:~#|@.;\`\/""*$,]*" Then` if `Target` is a *multi-cell* range.

Comment: The error is `Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error` This is when accessing a single cell. If I remove the ActiveCell command and use a MsgBox it is shown fine. So it is something relating to the command to change the background color.

Comment: I've updated the original question with some additional testing.. Which works. But not when the `If` is used.

Comment: Have you tried `Target.Value` or `Target.Text Like `? Also your Like string is probably going to give problems, as you need to enclose some characters in () as they have special meanings eg (!)

Comment: I've just realised what the issue is.  The cells it's trying to update are locked and the spreadsheet is protected.  As soon as I sort that it works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was caused by the cell I was trying to update being locked and the worksheet protected.  As soon as I removed that it the update worked correctly.

I've added some code to the sheet to unprotect the worksheet, update the cell and then re protect the sheet.